# Not naming a type - C++

Tags: c++, adobe

I am trying to convert an Adobe CS4 based plugin to CS5. This project has never been mine, this is the first time that i am seeing it.

When I compile the source with what i was given, I get errors like: Does not name a type

Example:

```
SPAPI SPErr SPBasicAcquireSuite( const char *name, int64 version, const void **suite );
```

I get that:

```
SPErr does not name a type
```

I dont see any classes with SPErr being defined, but I doubt that Adobe has left this out of the SDK.

I am using the PS_CS5_SDK_3 SDK

Comment: When you search the Adobe files for SPErr, what do you find? It could easily be that you're not including the proper files to define it.

Comment: Also make sure you specify the namespace, if it's in one.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the possibility to be specific because, of course, I do not have the code. Typically this problem occurs when a type, a class, is not correctly compiled by compiler... meaning that it cannot find it and asks: "what is this?". See macros, or better inspect your code in your hpp files... Probably when porting to CS5 some types have been removed or some...